# .htaccess hide get param from url and modify url

Tags: .htaccess

Right now I have the following urls 
http://example.com/products/?category=clothes
My main logic relies on the get parameter received from the url.
Is there any way I can change the structure to something like
http://example.com/products/clothes , and still have category param with clothes in it?
I tried using htaccess - 
I have tried this, but it did not work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)$ products/$1/?category=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the following in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/products/%1? [R=301,NC,L]
```

That will leave you with the URL: http://example.com/products/clothes

What we're doing here is grabbing the variable `category=` and whatever is associated with it is grabbed using `%1` and placed onto the end of the URL.

We then use a `?` to stop the original query, for example, `?category=clothes` from appearing on the end of the URL.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

Comment: This is not keeping the category param in the GET.Is there any way I can make it available via php $_GET, but dont have it displaying on the url?